# Problema ao realizar um select com JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou enfrentando um bug que não consigo descobrir uma solução.

Quando realizo um persist e em seguida o select o resultado recebido e normal, mas ao realizar um update e apos isso o select ao invés de exibir o resultado atualizado o resultado do select são os valores antigos, necessitando fechar o programa e abri novamente para testar. Embaixo estar o DAO desenvolvido para verificar o que pode estar ocasionando o problema.

```
public class ApartamentoDAO {
private EntityManager em;

/**
 * Contrutor para receber o Entity Manager
 * @param em -  parametro que recebe o Entity Manager
 */
public ApartamentoDAO(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param apt - Recebe o id do apartamento para verifica se existe no banco de dados.
 * 
 * @return ap - retorna um Apartamento existente no banco, ou retorna null.
 */
public Apartamento pesquisarAp(long apt) {
    System.out.println("o long da pesquisa e esse: " + apt);
    Apartamento ap = null;

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        ap = em.find(Apartamento.class, apt);
                em.getTransaction().commit();
                System.out.println("o apartamento e esse: "+ap.getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("o erro em questão foi esse: "+e);
    }
    return ap;

}

/**
 * Inserir um novo Apartamento
 * @param numero - id
 * @param andar - andar
 * @param descricao - descrição
 * @param valor  - valor do Ap
 * @param quantidade  - quantidade de hospede no Ap
 * @param ala - Ala onde se encontar o Ap
 */
public void inserirAp(Long numero, Long andar, String descricao, BigDecimal valor, Long quantidade, String ala) {

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Apartamento ap = new Apartamento(numero, andar, descricao, valor, quantidade, ala);
    em.persist(ap);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
}

/**
 * Alterar o Apartamento selecionado
 * @param numero - id
 * @param andar - andar
 * @param descricao - descrição
 * @param valor
 * @param quantidade
 * @param ala
 */
public void alterarAp(Long numero, long andar, String descricao, BigDecimal valor, Long quantidade, String ala) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Apartamento ap = new Apartamento(numero, andar, descricao, valor, quantidade, ala);

    em.merge(ap);


    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

}

/**
 * Lista todos os apartamentos existentes
 * 
 * @return resultado - retorna todos os apartamentos
 */
public List<Apartamento> listarAp() {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    String sql = "select a from Apartamento a";

    TypedQuery<Apartamento> query = em.createQuery(sql, Apartamento.class);


    List<Apartamento> resultado = query.getResultList();

    for (Apartamento result : resultado) {
        System.out.println(result.getId());
        System.out.println(result.getAndar());
        System.out.println(result.getDescricao());
        System.out.println(result.getValor());
        System.out.println("esse e o listar simples");
    }

    em.getTransaction().commit();


    return resultado;

}

public void deletarAp(long apt) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Apartamento ap =em.find(Apartamento.class, apt);
    em.remove(ap);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
}




public List<Apartamento> listarAp(String disponivel, Long apt) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    String sql = "select a from Apartamento a where a.status = :cDispo";

    TypedQuery<Apartamento> query =(TypedQuery<Apartamento>) em.createQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter("cDispo", disponivel);
    List<Apartamento> resultado = query.getResultList();

    sql = "select a from Apartamento a where a.id = :cApt";
    TypedQuery<Apartamento> query1 = (TypedQuery<Apartamento>) em.createQuery(sql);
    query1.setParameter("cApt", apt);
    Apartamento ap = query1.getSingleResult();
    resultado.add(ap);

    for (Apartamento result : resultado) {
        System.out.println(" esse e o resultado da querry do banco de dados "+result.getId());
    }

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return resultado;
}


    }
```

Classe de Exibição:

```
public class TelaPesq extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

EntityManager em;
List<Apartamento> listaAp;
JDesktopPane panel;

private Component getInstance() {
    return this;
}
/**
 * Creates new form TelaPesq
 *
 * @param panel
 */
public TelaPesq(JDesktopPane panel) {
    this.panel = panel;
    initComponents();
    menu();
    em = new JPAUtil().getEM();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    cbxAp = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    txaConteudo = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    btnEdit = new javax.swing.JButton();
    bntDelete = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setClosable(true);
    setIconifiable(true);
    setMaximizable(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setTitle("Visualizar");
    addInternalFrameListener(new javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener() {
        public void internalFrameActivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
            formInternalFrameActivated(evt);
        }
        public void internalFrameClosed(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameClosing(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameDeactivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameDeiconified(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameIconified(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
        public void internalFrameOpened(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
        }
    });

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(253, 244, 227));

    jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));

    cbxAp.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
            cbxApItemStateChanged(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Apartamentos");

    txaConteudo.setEditable(false);
    txaConteudo.setColumns(20);
    txaConteudo.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txaConteudo);

    btnEdit.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnEdit.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/icons8-Edit-32.png"))); // NOI18N
    btnEdit.setText("Editar");
    btnEdit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnEditActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    bntDelete.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    bntDelete.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/icons8-Delete Bin-32.png"))); // NOI18N
    bntDelete.setText("Excluir");
    bntDelete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            bntDeleteActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(cbxAp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 82, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 518, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btnEdit)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(bntDelete)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(cbxAp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 249, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnEdit)
                .addComponent(bntDelete))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    setBounds(0, 0, 754, 442);
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void cbxApItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                       
    escrever();        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

private void btnEditActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    editar();        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void bntDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    deletarAP();        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void formInternalFrameActivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {                                            
    pesquisarAp();        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton bntDelete;
private javax.swing.JButton btnEdit;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cbxAp;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea txaConteudo;
// End of variables declaration                   

/**
 * Metodo usado quando o Frame inicia para listar os apartamentos existentes
 */
private void pesquisarAp() {
    ApartamentoDAO dao = new ApartamentoDAO(em);
    listaAp = dao.listarAp();

    DefaultComboBoxModel ap = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

    listaAp.forEach((apt) -> {
        ap.addElement(apt.getId());
    });
    cbxAp.setModel(ap);

    escrever();

}

/**
 * Escrever na Area de texto as informaçoes pertinentes ao Apartamento
 */
private void escrever() {
    for (Apartamento apt : listaAp) {
        if (apt.getId() == Integer.parseInt(cbxAp.getSelectedItem().toString())) {
            txaConteudo.setText(
                    "Andar do apartamento: "        + apt.getAndar()        + "\n\n"
                    + "Valor do Apartamento: R$ "   + apt.getValor()        + "\n\n"
                    + "Quantidade de quartos: "     + apt.getQuantidade()   + "\n\n"
                    + "Ala: "                       + apt.getAla()          + "\n\n"
                    + "Descrição: \n"
                    + apt.getDescricao());
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Botão que encaminha para o formApart para alterar o apartamento
 */
private void editar() {
    TelaApart tela = new TelaApart();
    panel.add(tela);
    tela.alterar = true;
    if (cbxAp.getSelectedItem() != null) {
        Long apt = Long.parseLong(cbxAp.getSelectedItem().toString());
        tela.apt = apt;
        this.setVisible(false);
        tela.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não existe apartamento para ser editado!");
    }
}

/**
 * Botão que deleta o partamento selecionado
 */
private void deletarAP() {
    if (cbxAp.getSelectedItem() != null) {
        int aviso = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                null,
                "Tem certeza que deseja remover esse apartamento?",
                "Atenção",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (aviso == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            ApartamentoDAO dao = new ApartamentoDAO(em);
            dao.deletarAp(Long.parseLong(cbxAp.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Apartamento Deletado com Sucesso!");

            pesquisarAp(); 
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não existe apartamento para ser deletado!");
    }

}

private void menu() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JInternalFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    addInternalFrameListener(new javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener() {
        @Override
        public void internalFrameActivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
            formInternalFrameActivated(evt);
        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameClosed(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("teste closed");
        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameClosing(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
            int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Quer mesmo fechar essa janela?", "Fechar Janela",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                //call dispose to really close it
                dispose();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameDeactivated(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("teste deactivated");
        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameDeiconified(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("teste deiconfied");

        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameIconified(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {

            moveToFront();
        }

        @Override
        public void internalFrameOpened(javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("teste opened");

        }

    });

}
```

}

Classe da Entidade

```
 @Entity
 public class Apartamento implements Serializable {


@Id

private Long id;

private Long andar;

private String descricao;

private BigDecimal valor;

private Long quantidade;

private String ala;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "apartamento")
private List<Hospede> hospede;

public Apartamento() {
}

public Apartamento(Long id, Long andar, String descricao, BigDecimal valor, Long quantidade, String ala) {
    this.id = id;
    this.andar = andar;
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.valor = valor;
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
    this.ala= ala;
}





public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getAndar() {
    return andar;
}

public void setAndar(Long andar) {
    this.andar = andar;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public BigDecimal getValor() {
    return valor;
}

public void setValor(BigDecimal valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}

public Long getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
}

public void setQuantidade(Long quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
}

public List<Hospede> getHospede() {
    return hospede;
}

public void setHospede(List<Hospede> hospede) {
    this.hospede = hospede;
}

public String getAla() {
    return ala;
}

public void setAla(String ala) {
    this.ala = ala;
}
```

}

Classe TelaApart

```
private void salvarAP(boolean alterar) {

    if (txtNumero.getText().equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor, preencha todas as informações contendo (*)");
        marcacao();
    } else {

        txtDiaria.setText(txtDiaria.getText().replace(",", "."));
        Long numero = Long.parseLong(txtNumero.getText());
        ApartamentoDAO dao = new ApartamentoDAO(em);
        Apartamento ap = dao.pesquisarAp(numero);

        if (alterar && ap != null) {
            alterarAP(dao, numero);

        } else if (!alterar && ap != null) {
            int aviso = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                    null,
                    "Tem certeza que deseja alterar as informaçoes desse apartamento?",
                    "Aviso, Apartamento Existente!",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (aviso == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                alterarAP(dao, numero);

            }
        } else {
            int aviso = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                    null,
                    "Tem certeza que deseja cadastrar esse apartamento?",
                    "Aviso!",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (aviso == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                BigDecimal diaria;
                if(txtDiaria.getText().equals("")){
                    diaria = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);
                }else{
                 diaria =  new BigDecimal(txtDiaria.getText());
                }

                dao.inserirAp(Long.parseLong(txtNumero.getText()),
                        Long.parseLong(cbxAndar.getSelectedItem().toString()),
                        txaDesc.getText(),
                        diaria,
                        Long.parseLong(cbxQtd.getSelectedItem().toString()),
                        cbxAla.getSelectedItem().toString());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O Apartamento foi incluido com sucesso!");
                limpar();
            }
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Metodo usado para alterar um apartamento ja existente.
 *
 * @param dao - chamar o metodo alterarAP do ApartamentoDAO
 * @param numero - id do apartamento
 */
private void alterarAP(ApartamentoDAO dao, Long numero) {
    dao.alterarAp(
            numero,
            Long.parseLong(cbxAndar.getModel().getSelectedItem().toString()),
            txaDesc.getText(),
            new BigDecimal(txtDiaria.getText()),
            Long.parseLong(cbxQtd.getModel().getSelectedItem().toString()),
            cbxAla.getModel().getSelectedItem().toString()

    );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O Apartamento foi alterado com sucesso!");
    limpar();
}

/**
 * Metodo para limpar todos os campos de textos
 */
private void limpar() {
    txtNumero.setEditable(true);
    txtDiaria.setText("");
    txaDesc.setText("");
    txtNumero.setText("");
    txtNumero.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    txtDiaria.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    cbxAla.setSelectedIndex(0);
    cbxAndar.setSelectedIndex(0);
    cbxQtd.setSelectedIndex(0);

}

/**
 * Pesquisar o apartamento que deve ser alterado
 *
 * @param apt - numero do apartamento a ser pesquisado
 */
public void pequisarAP(long apt) {
    if (apt != 0l) {
        ApartamentoDAO dao = new ApartamentoDAO(em);
        Apartamento ap = dao.pesquisarAp(apt);
        System.out.println(ap.getDescricao());

        this.txtNumero.setText(ap.getId().toString());
        this.txtDiaria.setText(ap.getValor().toString());
        this.txaDesc.setText(ap.getDescricao());
        this.cbxAndar.setSelectedItem(ap.getAndar());
        txtNumero.setEditable(false);
    }

}
```

A Tela Apart estar somente os métodos pois o resto do código não coube no limite máximo do texto.

Comment: Coloque a classe `TelaApart` por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Você está fechando o seu `EntityManager` após alterar os dados do `Apartamento`:

```
public void alterarAp(Long numero, long andar, String descricao, BigDecimal valor, Long quantidade, String ala) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Apartamento ap = new Apartamento(numero, andar, descricao, valor, quantidade, ala);
    em.merge(ap);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close(); /*Remova essa linha*/
}
```

Remova a linha marcada.

Além disso, devido a forma como você moldou sua aplicação, você precisa evocar o método `pesquisarAp()` depois de editar a entidade para atualizar a sua lista.

Comment: Independente de fechar ou não o problema persiste.

Comment: @JulianoSilveira Quais são as outras classes do projeto? Pois testei aqui a classe que você colocou e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: adicionado a Entidade e a tela de exibição do projeto

Comment: @JulianoSilveira você já tentou armazenar o objeto devolvido pelo merge e usá-lo para verificar se os valores estão atualizados?

Comment: @JulianoSilveira Você tem que evocar o método `pesquisarAp()` para atualizar sua lista.

Comment: eu invoco, ao alterar eu abro novamente a tela pesquisar e quando ele abre o método `pesquisarAp()` e executado, mas parece que o JPA invés de acessar o banco para o select ele olha algum tipo de cache e não exibe a atualização. Segundo as minhas pesquisas o fato de trocar de tela para realizar o `merge `que estar de alguma forma causando esse problema

Comment: @JulianoSilveira O `merge` cria um novo objeto com as alterações e o retorna. Ele só causaria o problema caso você não estivesse realizando o `SELECT` novamente. Tente colocar um `System.out.println()` com alguma mensagem no `pesquisarAp()` para ter certeza que ele está sendo executado ao alterar alguma entidade.

Comment: sim, o merge estar realizando o update, quando confiro no banco a alteração estar lá.